# Does InetAddress.getLocalHost give ip address of Windows and Linux System?

Tags: java, network-programming

I am using `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`in my program which can be deployed on Windows and Linux servers.Does it give ip adress in both environments ?

Comment: If it didn't work the way no matter the underlying system, what would the use of it be? That's supposed to be one of the strong points of Java, platform independence.

Comment: Java is OS independent, Although in rare cases in has to be re-compiled for a specific IO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method gives an IP address on all platforms.  However, it may not give you the IP address that you expect.

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost--) says this:

> Returns the address of the local host. This is achieved by retrieving the name of the host from the system, then resolving that name into an InetAddress.
>
> If there is a security manager, its checkConnect method is called with the local host name and -1 as its arguments to see if the operation is allowed. If the operation is not allowed, an InetAddress representing the loopback address is returned.

There are a variety of scenarios where IP that an application is given is not the IP address that you want or need:

- If the application is sandboxed, the IP will be `127.0.0.1`.
- If local DNS is configured to return `127.0.0.1` for the host's name, then that is what you will get.  (I've seen systems misconfigured like that.)
- If the system has multiple NICs, the DNS lookup might give you the IP of a non-exposed NIC.
- If the system is actually a virtual machine, then the IP that the system sees may be different to the one that is exposed to the outside.
- If the system's IP is in a private IP range, then it won't be addressable "publicly".